# How can I add dependencies when I rewrite a module in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to rewrite the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item` class in Magento by adding the following line to my `di.xml`:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item"
            type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item"/>
```

Magento takes my `Vendor\Module`-class over it's default class, but I need to add some dependencies to it. Now I tried to add them by adjusting the `__construct()`-method and adding them there, but this doesn't work (which makes sence of course, because it breaks the chain for classes that try to extend the `Item`-object itself:

```
public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $htmlPagerBlock,
    array $data
) {
    $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    parent::__construct($url, $htmlPagerBlock, $data);
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Missing required argument $data of Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item.
```

So what's the proper way to get my helper in my rewritten object?

Comment: What if you move your `\Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper` in the end of your parameters list after the `array $data`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done is correct but you have made the final $data argument required by not adding `= []` after it as a default value.

Simply change `array $data` to `array $data = []`.

You may also have to clear the var/generation folder because you have changed the constructor params.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but I didn't clear my `var/generation` folder. Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your construct() method with below code,

```
public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $htmlPagerBlock,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    parent::__construct($url, $htmlPagerBlock, $data);
}
```

Remove `var/generation` folder and reload page.

Answer (score 0):

Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $data when the order of the constructor parameters was wrong.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,    
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $frameworkHelperDataHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,  
    array $data = [],        
    \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList
)
```

I was supposed to pass `array $data = [],` in the last

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,    
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $frameworkHelperDataHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
    array $data = []  
)
```